# Deleting a record from database using Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have created a Django app and tested the application's performance by populating some 10,0000  records. Now i want to delete it using a python script. Can somebody help me in doing this. This is the script i created to populate data into sql db.

```
def dumpdata():
    for i in range(2,10):
        userName = "Bryan"    
        designation = 'Technician '
        employeeID = 2312         
        dateOfJoin = '2009-10-10'    
        EmployeeDetails(userName= "Bryan",designation= 'Technician',employeeID= 2312,dateOfJoin= '2009-10-10').save()

dumpdata()
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`QuerySet.delete()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#delete)

```
EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(...).delete()
```

Comment: Just wanted to remind that `delete` method of your model won't be called when you remove your objects this way, so if you need to call it, just iterate through the queryset and run `delete()` for each instance.